# Mock: when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mocking

I am writing the unit tests for my REST-API and have some problems with the entities creation mocking. I don't know how can I mock the EntityManager. I tried the example below but I got an error.

My ControllerTest:

```
public class MControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks A a;
    @InjectMocks B b;
    @InjectMocks AController aController;
    @InjectMocks private AServiceImpl aServiceImpl;

    @Autowired WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    @Autowired private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                                 .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
                                 .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void postATest() throws Exception {

        a.setDDDD("XXX");

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = webApplicationContext.getBean(EntityManagerFactory.class);
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        when(this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()).thenReturn(entityManager);

        when(aServiceImpl.createEntity(isA(A.class))).thenReturn(a);

        b.setCCCC;
        a.setMovieTranslations(Arrays.asList(b));

        when(aServiceImpl.createEntity(isA(B.class))).thenReturn(a);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/path")
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    }
```

The createEntityMethod:

```
public Object createEntity(T t) {
    try {
        entityManager.persist(t);
        return t;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | EntityExistsException | ...
}
```

The error log:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

    at com.x.server.controller.MControllerTest.postATest(MControllerTest.java:121)
```

When I don't inject a mock object on the EntityManager, I got a nullpointer exception by the persist method with this error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.x.server.serviceImpl.AManageServiceImpl.createEntity(AManageServiceImpl.java:45)
    at com.eza.server.controller.MControllerTest.postATest(MControllerTest.java:123)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I wonder why you mix Spring an Mockito like that. Either you need these "real" beans, then you're creating an integratoin test and you most likely don't need mockito. Or you're creating a unit test where every dependent bean is mocked.

Comment: you are right. Thanks. You comment solve my problem. It is working now. I only use mockito right now.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please write an answer with your now working code and what you've changed, so future readers can learn from it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it. I just removed some line of code with the entitymanager interface and it works.

```
public class MControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks A a;
    @InjectMocks B b;
    @InjectMocks AController aController;

    @Autowired WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    @Autowired private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                                 .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain)
                                 .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void postMovieTest() throws Exception {

        a.setDDDD("XXX");
        b.setCCCC;
        a.setMList(Arrays.asList(b));


        mockMvc.perform(post("/path")
            .content(asJsonString(a))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    }
```

asJsonString is by me self write method to convert object in json

Cheers

Comment: not able to understand, what you changed. can you please explain a bit more.